# What can an assertion test that running the actual code cannot?

Tags: unit-testing, programming-practices, testing

I'm currently learning Jest, Enzyme, Detox and testing in general, but I'm still trying to grasp the benefit of testing.  From what I understand, testing is about creating hypothetical situations. Let's say when a hypothetical parameter is passed into a component, what is the expected result versus the actual result?  For example, Jest goes so far as mocking functions, classes, modules, and API calls to create these hypothetical situations.

I'd understand if the test runs the all the hypothetical scenarios possible without me having to individually list all assertions, then creating a test makes sense.  For example, if I wanted to test a function:

```js
test('the data is peanut butter', done => {
  function callback(data) {
    try {
      expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
      done();
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  }

  fetchData(callback);
});
```

I have to list a multiple hypothetical results myself individual i.e. "peanut butter, strawberry jam, butter, etc" to see if they'd all return expected results.  I'm not sure how this is different from me just running the actual code and finding out the results or the errors or creating arbitrary parameters myself and passing them. If I didn't want the API to be hit, I can just create a development server.  Plus, tools like Typescript and esLint provides some safeguard during the initial coding and refactoring, granted they're not providing expected behaviors of functions and components.

I've looked at the documentations and the examples from tutorials, but I still have yet to find a good real life example of testing that I can't do by simply just running the code. Does the app navigate to another screen? Does a modal open? Is a component visible when an event happens? I can't fathom the benefit of running the tests on these over simply running the code. What am I missing?

**update**
I have no idea why this is getting downvoted, but thank you for those taking your time to answer my question.

Answer (score 5):

## Time

A large code base is comprised of hundreds upon thousands upon millions of lines of code, third party libraries, and online ever-green services.

If we want to deploy that code for use by a user we have to prove that it works. Which means running through every possible button click, screen hide, modal dialogue, network request, database operation, etc... until we feel safe in saying that:

1. it won't blow up in production costing the business millions of dollars.
2. its not going to immediately liquidate the business assets and send them to bank account on some tropical island
3. that if a freak spate of bus accidents take the entire team down, that someone could theoritically change the tax code to avoid a regulatory fine.

How many man hours do you think are needed, over how many weeks to certify a single version of the code base?

Now businesses want to have their code today, and don't want to pay through the nose for it.

What is a poor (in both time and funds) developer to do?

You could write out a lot of documentation, and hand that over to a legion of monkeys...

- But monkeys need to eat,
- and monkeys get bored,
- and monkeys make mistakes...

Also that documentation will get out of date, and the monkeys don't care to tell you that.

How about a robot monkey?

- They don't eat
- they never get bored
- and the don't make mistakes... the might do the wrong thing very quickly, but that is because the documentation is wrong.

And how much do they cost? *Almost nothing (the time to write)*

And how hard is it to maintain the documentation? *It will tell you when something is wrong (it won't compile)*

And how long will it take to verify a version of the software? *Pretty quickly (as many robot monkeys you want to throw at it)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I get that it verifies whether something works or not. My question is specifically in regards to the type of testings done by the libraries mentioned above like Jest, Enzyme, Detox, etc where the assertions are usually a single instance of something that has to happen which can be tested by just running the code itself to see if it works.  What exactly does a single assertion test that running the actual code can't test?

Comment: @Kevvv The assertion tests that your code works *correctly*. An empty method runs very fast and will never crash, but it almost certainly doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @Kevvv I think you need to take a look at Kent Beck 3X presentation. I think you are having trouble seeing the point because you are seeing the problem from a different context. eg: I can manually test the lot in five minutes and thats it. Which means unit tests are an expense as it takes way longer to craft them than five minutes. Think of them like scaffolding, you don't need to erect a scaffold to construct a small toy house, but you had better have one for that sky scrapper. (Also i've seen some very complex toy houses that used scaffolding well)

Comment: I just checked out Kent Beck 3X presentation, but I'm looking for a little less abstract explanation. In your scaffolding analogy, what can assertions provide that the code editor's error catching ability can't?

Comment: ... logic errors. This might sound inane but how about a loan? People can get very upset when something is wrong with money. How would you verify that you are correctly calculating the interest? You can easily run the code and see that it works, but is it the correct value? Imagine a nasty loan where the balance changes hourly, or the interest rate changes by day. How can you ensure that the amount of interest charged at the end of the period is right?

Comment: i feel like the code editor, typescript, and other lint software are all able to catch logic errors as well

Comment: @Kevvv No they won't. A Logic error does not invalidate the algorithm itself, it invalidates the algorithm with regard to an external context. Those tools will detect syntax errors, type errors and stylistic errors such as formatting and general complexity. But they won't catch an off by one, or a manipulation that produces a a semantically valid result. The problem is that while it is semanticly valid, it is not the result the human is looking for. So again how would those tools understand what interest on a loan is? If they do, why are you even writing code? The tool obviously knows better.

Answer (score 3):

KainO_O has given a perfect answer to the actual question but I think a bigger picture is useful here:

Things like unit tests seem stupid in school because you're not in a situation where they provide any real value.  You write a piece of code, you turn it in, that's it, you're not coming back.  You probably test it once whether you do so manually or by unit tests--and in that situation the unit tests are a cost (you could have a bug in them) but almost no value.

In the real world, however, you are coming back, likely again and again.  You pick up that old code and change something--did you break something else in the process?  You can either go through everything your program can do (prohibitive) or you can write code that goes through everything it can do.  Now the value of the unit test goes way, way up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let's say I do come back to my code again and again. When my code breaks, my code editor or Typscript or eslint provide me with the information on why it's breaking. I can still troubleshoot the errors without using the assertions.  Are these testing libraries useful in the sense that they provide complementary information that your code editor doesn't provide like what specific expected behavior didn't actualize, instead of just pointing at the location of the error like the code editor does?

Comment: In that sense, they're good in catching some behaviors that might have slipped through the safeguards of your code editor.  Also, I can look for a specific behavior I might forget to check in the future, such as, I want the modal to be visible after a certain event.

Comment: @Kevvv Unit tests aren't about troubleshooting, they are about finding out that there is trouble in the first place.  And your editor can only point out exceptions, it can't point out incorrect behavior.  Take yesterday--the exception was a duplicate of a key marked unique.  What was the real error?  Attempting to validate some data that hadn't been loaded.

Comment: not sure if i'm understanding you correctly because pointing out an exception and finding out a problem seems like a semantic difference with a same meaning. If I set up an assertion, I'm trying to see if an exception causes an error, am I not? Which is the same as running my code and finding out if it causes an error.  If you meant, by writing an assertion before coding, I can think about what the code is intended to do, that's just a matter of a writing practice, not a functionality of the assertion

Comment: @Kevvv The point is the exception occurred at a location far removed from the actual error and the real error it should never have gone down that path in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Besides saving time, unit tests can test error handling much more easily than you can. They can also test complex processes like asynchronous execution and allow easier debugging of code that uses things like that.